# How to set clang-cl to c++14 or c++1z?

Tags: clang, visual-studio-2015, clang++, llvm-clang

I've tried to set clang-cl arguments with -std=c++14, -std=c++1z, -std=c++1y. And they don't work. I am using clang 3.7 pre-build for windows x64 and VS 2015.

Comment: I don't think you can set the language standard in cl mode, clang's always targeting the latest C++ standard there (like MSVC).

Answer (score 5):

The Clang page linked below claims `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14` as well as `-std=c++1z` are all supported commands. Now considering that `clang-cl` is, as far as I know, `clang --driver-mode=cl` which aims to emulate MSVC `cl.exe`. I can't see why this would eliminate support for platform agnostic features like c++ standards.

http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

**EDIT**: In another post on this same topic, it was mentioned that in order to pass arguments to clang itself when in `clang-cl` mode you must use:

`-Xclang <arg>         Pass <arg> to the clang compiler`

This is referenced here:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl

Comment: I have tried to add these in VS compiler settings, and nothing worked.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'they don't work'?

Comment: clang-cl won't recognize these arguments

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that `-std=c++14` is supposed to work. Clang-cl is a separate driver for clang (not that separate as it is just a rename of clang), which supports the MSVC arguments instead of the GCC arguments.

An overview of all supported command line arguments which are supported can be found [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl), which doesn't contain this flag.

From my understanding, clang-cl takes over the C++ features supported by MSVC instead of using the standard (+ some extensions not supported by MSVC). This is especially important as MSVC (pre-2015) did not differentiate on standard, making for instance MSVC 2013 contain features from c++11, c++14 and c++17, while other features from these same standards ain't supported or ain't working correctly.

So to be able to support compilation of MSVC, clang can't support the `-std=c++11` flag without breaking compilation. (Though it might be what you want)
That said, [MSVC 2015 supports /std:c++14](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/), so possibly clang-cl should be supported for this too. (Sounds like a bug/feature request)